# 3 dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create a 3D array in PHP about the market. I already have done creation. I used the market name as one array, products as second array and amount in each month as a third.
Now I need to sum every products in market. For example

```
bread = 126100
```

Sum of all bread amount in all markets together.

I will share my code :

```
$market = array(
"1" =>array
("bread"=>array(1000,6000,1550,2000,4000,6550,7000,4000,7000,1000,2000,3000), 
"milk"=>array(3000,4000,5000,6000,5000,4000,7000,6000,7000,4000,2000,5000),
"cheese"=>array(2000,3000,2000,1000,4000,3000,3000,5000,4000,3000,4000,4000),
"juice "=>array(2000,4000,5000,4000,3000,4000,1000,1000,1000,2000,1000,2000)), 
"2" => array
("bread"=>array(3000,3000,4000,3000,6000,6000,4000,3000,4000,3000,6000,6000),
 "milk"=>array(6000,3000,4000,5000,4000,3000,5000,4000,3000,5000,6000,5000),
 "cheese"=>array(3000,3000,3000,5000,2000,2000,3000,4000,4000,3000,2000,1000),
 "juice"=>array(1000,1000,4000,3000,3000,1000,2000,2000,1000,1000,4000,3000)), 
 "3"=> array
 ("bread"=>array(7000,4000,3000,2000,2000,2000,4000,2000,1000,1000,1000,1000), 
  "milk"=>array(3000,3000,2000,2000,1000,2000,3000,2000,2000,2000,1000,1000),
 "cheese"=>array(1000,1000,2000,2000,2000,3000,2000,3000,3000,2000,1000,1000),
 "juice"=>array(1000,900,900,1000,2000,2000,1000,1000,2000,3000,1000,900))
  );
```

I already tried something like this but didn't work exactly like I wanted.

```
function searchItemsByKey($array, $key)
{
 $results = array();

  if (is_array($array))
    {
      if (isset($array[$key]) && key($array)==$key)
       $results[] = $array[$key];

   foreach ($array as $sub_array)
    $results = array_merge($results, searchItemsByKey($sub_array, $key));
 }

  return  $results;
 }
 $results =searchItemsByKey($market, 'bread');
  print_r($results);
```

Comment: Iterate over array, sum values under each key of subarray.

Comment: (… and if any of those mentioned steps makes you go “don’t know how to do that” again - then maybe you go should work through a couple beginner tutorials that explain some basics first.)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$total = [];

foreach ($market as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $product => $prices) {
        $total[$key][$product]['total'] = array_sum($prices);
    }
}
print_r($total); exit;
```

In the above code, `$key` is the market, `$product` is the product name, and `total` is the total value of the product in that market.

You can use `array_sum()` function to sum the array values.
PHP Official Documentation: [PHP array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 0):

Do this. Then you will get your market-wise total product

```
        $marketProducts = [];
        foreach ($market as $key => $products) {
            foreach ($products as $name => $amount) {
                $marketProducts[$key][$name] = array_sum($amount);
            }
        }
        dd($marketProducts);
```